# how to use custom regular expression for more than one call?

Tags: python, regex, text, multiline, multilinestring

edit: This part was solved, but I have one last problem with my code, see last answer.

I have a textfile structured as follow:

```
Name1 (Middlename1) LastName
Birthyear
Name2 (Middlename2) LastName
Birthyear
...
NameN (MiddlenameM) LastName
Birthyear
```

I'm trying to use RE to find the name and the year automatically but I don't know how to combine the two REs since both information are not on the same line:

```
import re
regexp = re.compile(  r'(( )*)(?P<name>([a-zA-Z]*)( [a-zA-Z]+)? ROCHE)\n'
                      r'(( )*)(?P<year>18\d\d)\n'
                   )
```

The two REs are working independently but not together. How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: "RE" stands for "Regular Expression" so "RE Expression" means "Regular Expression Expression" :)

Comment: what are you *actually* trying to accomplish give us some expected input and some expected output

Comment: So basically, I have two different files. By extracting the information in the first one with RE I should be able to find the matching information in the second one.

Comment: Can't you just concatenate the two expressions?

Comment: I need to take the Name and Year of the first person and look for a match in the second file, then the second Name and year and so on until the end of the file. How do I use RE on two consecutive lines?

Comment: _ look for a match in the second file_ .... _use RE on two consecutive lines_ What does a second file have to do with this? Is it two lines or two files?

Answer (score 1):

You want *one* regex that scans a string that spans across *two* lines. You then want to find successive matches. But first:

Names, at least in English-speaking countries, can contain hyphens (Anne-Marie), apostrophes (O'Donnell), periods (John Q. Public), etc. So I am using a regular expression that allows these characters. Also, people may have more than one middle name. What I am trying to illustrate is how to iterate through name/year pairs; you can customize the actual regex to suit your own particular requirements.

Regex:

```
^(?P<name>(?:[a-z.'-]+(?:\s+[a-z.'-]+)*))\n(?P<year>\d{4})$  Flags: re.M|re.I
```

1. `^` Matches the start start of a line.
2. `[a-z.'-]+` Matches one or more alpha, period, ', or - characters. This is a **name element**.
3. `(?:\s+[a-z.'-]+)*` Matches one or more white space characters followed by **name element**. This is repeated 0 or more times. Thus the named group **name** consists of 1 or more **name elements** separated by one or more white space characters.
4. `\n` Matches a newline.
5. `(?P<year>\d{4})$` Matches 4 digits followed by the end of line or the end of string.

The MULTILINE flag treats the `^` and `$` anchors special so that they match in addition to the start and end of string, the start and end of a line.

The code relies on `re.finditer` to find successive matches:

```
import re

text = """John Doe
1921
John Q. Public
1987
Anne-Marie Smith
1989
Paul O'Donnell
2001
J. P. Marquand
1893
"""

regexp = re.compile(r"^(?P<name>(?:[a-z.'-]+(?:\s+[a-z.'-]+)*))\n(?P<year>\d{4})$", flags=re.M|re.I)
for m in regexp.finditer(text):
    name = m['name']
    year = m['year']
    # do something with name and year in the second file. Here we are just printing the values.
    print(name, year)
```

Prints:

```
John Doe 1921
John Q. Public 1987
Anne-Marie Smith 1989
Paul O'Donnell 2001
J. P. Marquand 1893
```

Comment: @usr2564301 I added an explanation about the MULTILINE flag.

Comment: @BoobooThank you for your help, I think I have a problem with the MULTILINE flag. My string is in a text file, so to open it im using: 'open("filename.txt","r")'. And to use multiline flags I need to have a string in a multiline string symbol.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by: **And to use multiline flags I need to have a string in a multiline string symbol (""" something """)**. For what it's worth, the text file can be read into variable `text` as follows: `with open("filename.txt") as f: text = f.read()`

Comment: You could probably also do without the MULTILINE flag altoghether with: `(?P<name>(?:[a-z.'-]+(?:\s+[a-z.'-]+)*))\n(?P<year>\d{4})`, but this should **`not`** be necessary,

Comment: Ok thank is because I wasn't using f.read() in the finditer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read the file first into `text` and then use `text` as the argument to `finditer`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `re.MULTILINE`

```
r = re.compile(r'(( )*)(?P<name>([a-zA-Z]*)( [a-zA-Z]+)?)(( )+)(?P<surname>([a-zA-Z]+))\n(?P<year>18\d\d)', re.MULTILINE)

m = r.match("""Jan Sebastian  Bach
1892""")
```

**Update #1**
More complete example with reading two lines from file and then another two lines.

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'(( )*)(?P<name>([a-zA-Z]*)( [a-zA-Z]+)?)(( )+)(?P<surname>([a-zA-Z]+))\n(?P<year>18\d\d)', re.MULTILINE)

with open('people.txt') as f:
    while True:
        line1 = f.readline()
        line2 = f.readline()
        if not line2: break
        m = r.match(line1+line2)
        print("name:%s, surname:%s, year:%s" % (m.group('name'), m.group('surname'), m.group('year')))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I have a problem with the MULTILINE flag. My string is in a text file, so to open it I'm using: 'open("filename.txt","r")'. And to use multiline flags I need to have a string in a multiline string symbol (""" something """).